# Are all properties entangled when one property is entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

When one or more particles are quantum entangled by say their spin property, do their other measurable properties (e.g., momentum, polarization, whatever?) become entangled as well?

Answer (score 2):

No, other properties do not necessarily become entangled.

Example:
You can take twin photons from type-II parametric down conversion. These two photons are entangled in energy and momentum, but not in polarization.

For more information about this example, see: [Physical Review A 50, 5122](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.50.5122) (free version available [here](http://128.197.153.21/alexserg/PRA_50_5122.pdf)).

As described in the article, terms containing energy and momentum of the twin photons are not factorizable whereas the part describing the polarization of the photons is factorized, like

$$
\left|\psi\right>=\left|0\right>+\sum_{k,k'}g(\omega_{ok})\delta(\omega_{ok}+\omega_{ek'}-\omega_p)h(L\Delta_{kk'})\hat a^\dagger_{ok}\hat a^\dagger_{ek}\left|0\right>
$$

The delta function and $h(x)$ result in entanglement of energy and momentum respectively, where the part determining the polarization is written in a product of the two polarizations ($o$ for ordinary and $e$ for extraordinary polarization).

Comment: this answer is nice, but the article you cite is behind paywall. Can you provide some accessible reference, or quote the relevant parts of the article, or just expand a little on your argument?

Comment: A free pdf of the article [can be found here](http://128.197.153.21/alexserg/PRA_50_5122.pdf) (for now).

Comment: Doesn't there exists types of entanglements, where more $2$ properties are simultaneously entangled?For example,hyperentangled states or entanglement duality "http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/16/8/08301".